# Exporting movie from Premiere Elements 13 seems to only give audio

Tags: premiere-elements

After creating a movie from some GoPro footage, using Premiere Elements 13 on Microsoft Windows 10, I attempted to export to 1080p 25fps mpeg using the basic export option.

All looked good but when I tried to play back in Windows Media Player, all I get is audio.

I'm new to using Premiere - is there something obvious I'm missing? I didn't see any other export options.

Mediainfo gives me this:

[image]

Comment: What does either Mediainfo or ffprobe say about the file?

Comment: Good point - it could just be a corrupted export. I will try both of them this evening and report back.

Comment: One of the worst features of Premier is the ambiguity of what is selected for export.  You can be looking at your sequence all day, but if you have something other than that sequence selected in your Project window, Premier will export *that*.

Comment: Looks good. Which OS? WMP needs decoder for MPEG-2 in Vista or earlier. Try VLC or see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306331

Comment: Okay - I see where the problem lies...VLC plays the video perfectly, but WMP fails. It's a WMP issue, not a Premiere issue.